# Change font, font colour and font size of automatic text in a text box

Tags: excel

In Excel, when I create a text box and enter text, I can highlight it and change the font type, size and colour.  GREAT!  However when I enter a formula so that the text in the text box will be the value of a cell, I cannot select the text within the text box anymore, nor can I find a way to change the font type, size or colour.

Is there a way to do this without changing the font in the rest of the worksheet?

EDIT:  I found a work around.  Seems automatic text takes on the format of the source cell.  I created an out of the way intermediate cell when I formatted the text the way I need it then I point the text box at that intermediate cell.  I was hoping for a way to do it without an intermediate step, but I will live with it for now unless someone else has a better suggestion.

Comment: What version of Excel?  In 2010 at least you can change the font, colour, size, fill and apply WordArt styles independently of the format in the linked cell - just select the text box and use the normal formatting tools (Home ribbon or Drawing Tools/Format ribbon).

Comment: I can do what you describe as long as its text I type in the text box, but as soon as I put =$B$2, then I can no longer formate the information that gets displayed from cell B2 unless I format it in cell B2.  Those formats carry over to the text box.  I am using excel 2013